# Where did I move my file to? (mv in git bash)

Tags: terminal

I'm using Git Bash on Windows and just moving my files around locally. Here's my folder path:

```
/e/Python/Python---CS-170/CS170_homework/
```

I tried to move my files from Python---CS-170 to the sub folder CS170_homework and it a bit of curiousity, I typed this:

```
mv Python---CS-170/CS170_homework /
```

Now all the content in the folder Python---CS-170 is moved somewhere. Can you tell me where the files are moved to? I know the place it went to is "/", but what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try running on the Git Bash these commands:

```
cygpath -w /
```

On my system I am getting output as:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\
```

You can navigate to the folder using explorer to find the files you are looking for.

[Here](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html) is the documentation for the utility.

Comment: That's a big save, thank you so much and I also learned a new terminal command.

Comment: But it is only applicable to Cygwin and MinGW/Msys Bash shell will not work on Linux etc.